# Start-Process : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Command'

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016, windows-server-core

Strangest error. Im attempting to run an elevated powershell process in order to install an application on a headless windows server 2016 core container.

steps to reproduce this:

- start the container in interactive mode (`docker start mycontainer -i`)
- from cmd - `powershell`
- from powershell session prompt `Start-Process -Command PowerShell -Verb RunAs`
- receive the unrecognized error statement

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because [Start-Process does not have a parameter called -Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

You probably mean `-FilePath`